# Maximum page width

Tags: width, chromium-embedded

I have inherited some code where we are using CEFSharp to host plotly charts within a WPF application. It seems that one team has pushed this possibly beyond its limits and sometimes the chart and page it is housed in needs to be very wide meaning that the CEFSharp control is also very wide. Beyond a certain point (at around 0x4000 / 16385) it seems to stop rendering beyond that width. Is there a limit to the usable width of the control? Can I find this documented somewhere so that I can steer the development towards a compatible solution?